# Question migrated to incorrect sister site

Tags: discussion, migration

A question was posted to stackoverflow but was then moved over to Serverfault:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119359/best-tool-to-visualize-network-with-40-000-nodes-and-5-million-edges-closed

Those who moved it did not understand the question as it is really not appropriate for Serverfault.  The question seems more appropriate for SuperUser or StackOverflow.  Is there any mechanism for undoing the move to Serverfault?

Comment: This is a dupe of older questions too, looking for link....  To answer your question, though: No, there is no unmigrate option.  The short version of the dupes I'm thinking of is basically what you said.  Your high rep on site A means that you know something doesn't belong on site A, not necessarily that you know which site it _does_ belong on.

Comment: The question really is poorly asked. It appears like the intent was not clear to the audience on other SO or SF. For example I am not entirely sure if your computer networks and instead something to do with graph theory.

Comment: All you can do is flag one of the posts for moderator attention and hope that they agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

That question, as stated, is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.  It is about software, but it isn't about *programming*.  I really think Server Fault is the best place for it, as that's where it seems most likely to get a good answer.  I know it does seem appropriate to ask it on Super User, but I think the folks over at Server Fault are more likely to use an application like the one described in the question, so they're more likely to know where to find it.